# Forge Viewer, PDF mirrored

Tags: pdf, autodesk-forge

I correctly setup Forge Viewer for loading local PDFs, using integrated extension **Autodesk.PDF**.
Some PDF are visualized in mirrored view, unlike when opened in Acrobat Reader.
I do not make any call to rotate/resize PDF, so we think the problem is related to these PDF and how **Autodesk.PDF** render it.

I can share PDF if needed for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-basic-app/blob/experiment/pdf/public/main.js) approach, I was able to reproduce your issue with Viewer 7.37.
Let's use one of the pdfs provided as an example:

Here we have the pdf with Viewer 7.37:

[image: PDF USING VIEWER 7.37]

And below, we have the one using Viewer 7.38:

[image]

This might occur on your end due to a caching problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please ensure you have the latest version ([7.38](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#id1) as of March 2021). If the problem persists, please share the PDF.

Comment: Yes, I have latest version, 7.38.0. Here [PDFs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U5ANSuzMJvuRu_kVWOO260Os71JMTK21/view?usp=sharing)